# Continuous image of the closure of a set in a compact space is closure of image

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Page $37$ of [this](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Eeisner/book-EFHN.pdf) book, chapter focus on topological dynamics. They here reference a fact from topology that I am unfamiliar with:

> Since the projection $\pi:H\to K$ is continuous, and $H$ is compact, $\pi(\overline{A})=\overline{\pi(A)}$

The set $A$ in question is the forward orbit of a point $(x_0,1)\in H$, under a continuous dynamic. $H$ is a product set $K\times G$, where $G$ is a compact group and $K$ is a compact topological space.

My only thoughts:

The closure of $A$ is of course a closed set, and closed subsets of compact spaces are themselves compact. Perhaps if we cover the forward orbit by open neighbourhoods of every point in the orbit, which is somehow meaningful. I know that $\pi(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{\pi(A)}$ since $\pi$ is continuous, but where compactness is relevant, and how to show the reverse direction, is beyond me.

Comment: $H$ compact implies that $\pi$ is closed, so that $\pi(\overline{A})$ is closed. Now $\pi(\overline{A})$ is a closed set containing $\pi(A)$, from which you get $\overline{\pi(A)}\subseteq\pi(A)\subseteq\pi(\overline{A})$. You already had the other inclusion and we are done.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I don’t know much topology. Why does $H$ compact imply $\pi$ closed?

Comment: here the whole product is compact so the first two lines in Michael's answer explain why $\pi$ is closed. In general the projection $\pi\colon X\times Y\to Y$ is closed whenever $X$ is compact, regardless of $Y$, this is a consequence of the [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma)

Comment: Sorry. I’ve read the tube lemma - thanks for that - and Wikipedia calmly rephrases it in terms of closed maps, but my basic understanding of topology has me befuddled. How do I go from “If $N$ is open and contains a slice then it contains a tube” to “projections are closed maps”? @AlessandroCodenotti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\overline{A}$ is compact as the closed subset of a compact space. Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. So $\pi(\overline{A})$ is compact. At least if $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, $\pi(\overline{A})$ is then also closed. So $\pi(\overline{A})$ is a closed set containing $\pi(A)$. Since $\overline{\pi(A)}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\pi(A)$, we have $\overline{\pi(A)}\subseteq \pi(\overline{A})$.